# Jolt transformation OMH Mapping to FHIR

Tags: json, mapping, jolt, hl7-fhir

Input:

```json
{
  "heart_rate": {
    "value": 70,
    "unit": "beats/min"
  },
  "effective_time_frame": {
    "time_interval": {
      "start_date_time": "11/01/22 22:14:21"
    }
  },
  "descriptive-statistics": "minimum"
}
```

Jolt Spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "effective_time_frame": {
        "time_interval": {
          "start_date_time": "effectiveDateTime"
        }
      },
      "heart_rate": {
        "value": "valueQuantity.value"
      }
    }
    }
,
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "effectiveDateTime": "=concat(@(day),'-',@(month),'-2022')",
      "month": "=substring(@(effective_time_frame.time_interval.start_date_time),3,5)",
      "day": "=substring(@(effective_time_frame.time_interval.start_date_time),4,5)"
    }
  }
,
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "valueQuantity": {
        "code": "/min",
        "system": "http://unitsofmeasure.org",
        "unit": "beats/minute"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Output:

```
{
  "effectiveDateTime" : "11/01/22 22:14:21",
  "valueQuantity" : {
    "value" : 70,
    "unit" : "beats/minute",
    "code" : "/min",
    "system" : "http://unitsofmeasure.org"
  }
}
```

We have a date in the format (xxx/xx/xx/) and we want it in this format (xxxx-xx-xx) without the time.
Maybe someone can help me. We need to change this as part of a project and unfortunately have no idea how Jolt transformation works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use ***concat*** function within **modify** transformation spec, but should bring from one level going up the tree as an example **`@(1,year)`**,  and use **`overwrite`** style instead of **`default`** for the transformation in order to overwrite the existing value of `effectiveDateTime` with the new one such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "effective_time_frame": {
        "time_interval": {
          "day": "=substring(@(1,start_date_time),0,2)",
          "month": "=substring(@(1,start_date_time),3,5)",
          "year": "=substring(@(1,start_date_time),6,8)",
          "start_date_time": "=concat('20',@(1,year),'-',@(1,month),'-',@(1,day))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "effective_time_frame": {
        "time_interval": {
          "start_date_time": "effectiveDateTime"
        }
      },
      "heart_rate": {
        "value": "valueQuantity.value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "valueQuantity": {
        "code": "/min",
        "system": "http://unitsofmeasure.org",
        "unit": "beats/minute"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]